# Binding to reference of type discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm dealing with a cpp course at my university, and I came across a problem which I wasn't able to solve by myself. The main.cpp is given by the lecturer and you have to make the header file for it to work. In that one the

```
Tedge &operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec)
```

function should return the Tedge to be overwritten, but I'm getting an

```
error: binding 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to reference of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&' discards qualifiers
```

error. Why is it happening when nothing is const, and how can I solve it? When I remove the & before the operator() it works, but then the program can't set the variable's value.

Oh and we need to program in C++98.

main.cpp

```
#include "lgraph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int yourMark = 1;

    LGraph<int, std::string, true> dg;
    dg.add(1);
    dg.add(2);
    dg.add(3);
    dg.add(8);
    dg.add(2,1, "Baker street");
    dg.add(1, 3, "Big street");
    dg.add(2, 3, "Small street");
    dg.add(8, 3, "Dog street");
    const LGraph<int, std::string, true> cdg = dg;
    LGraph<char, std::string, false> ug;
    ug.add('A');
    ug.add('G');
    ug.add('H');
    ug.add('A', 'H', "Stackoverflow street");

    yourMark += cdg.is_directed() + ug.is_directed();

    if(!cdg.has("Nowheretobefound") && "Big street" == cdg(1,3)){
        yourMark = ug.countNodes();
    }

    dg(2, 3) = "Flower street";

    std::cout<<dg(2,3) << std::endl;

    if(4 == cdg.countEdges() && !dg.has("Small street")) {
        dg.remove(1);
        yourMark = ug.countEdges() + dg.countNodes();
    }
    std::cout << "Your mark is " << yourMark << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

lgraph.h

```
#ifndef LGRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#define LGRAPH_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


template<typename Tnode, typename Tedge, bool isDir>

class LGraph {
    typename std::vector<Tnode> nodes;
    typename std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>> edges;
    bool isdir;
public:
    LGraph():isdir(isDir){};

    void add(Tnode value) {
        nodes.push_back(value);
    }

    void add(Tnode n, Tnode n2, Tedge e) {
        edges.insert(std::pair<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>(e, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>(n, n2)));
    }

    bool is_directed() const{
        return isdir;
    }

    bool has(Tedge edge) const{
        bool l = false;
        for(typename std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end() && !l; it++) {
            l = it -> first == edge;
        }

        return l;
    }

    int countNodes() {
        return nodes.size();
    }

    const Tedge operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec) const {
        for(typename std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++) {
            if(it->second.first == first && it->second.second == sec) {
                return it->first;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    Tedge &operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec){
        for(typename std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++) {
            if(it->second.first == first && it->second.second == sec) {
                return it->first;
            }
        }
    }

    const int countEdges() const {
        return edges.size();
    }

    void remove(const Tnode &node) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            if(nodes[i] == node) {
                int currentSize = nodes.size();
                nodes.erase(nodes.begin() + i);
                nodes.resize(currentSize-1);
            }
        }
    }

};

#endif // LGRAPH_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: "we need to program in C++98" but error says `const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>`.. check headers and compiler settings?

Comment: Map keys are const-qualified so `it->first` returns a `Tedge const &`. It is not clear why are you using `map` here. You never take advantage of fast `find` method and instead just iterate over entire map.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather have a map where the node pair is the key and the `Tedge` is the value?

Comment: Why are you doing a linear search over an associative map? That's like [trying to club someone to death with a loaded Uzi](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#1992).

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the error indicates a "recent" (7-year-old) GCC ABI, which is orthogonal to the language standard subset used in the source code.  The problem lies in the source code not the compiler settings.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb - I understand that the problem is in the project source code, but nevertheless, seeing cxx11 for a build intended for c98 looks fishy to me. If '98 is the goal of this assignement, I suppose headers providing `std::__cxx11` shouldn't be used at all.. That's why I wrote it.. but then, I'm no expert on how GCC's support for various standard levels is designed. If you can confirm that it's ok and normal under `-std=c++98`/etc then OK, thank you, I'll make sure to remember that..

Comment: You can see why I used map in the marked answers' comments. Also you can see why I used cpp11 reference instead of cpp98. (Hint: I don't know how to change the compiler, because this is the first time I ran a program on a computer...). However I was told that you can use any compiler on the exam, but you can't use newer stuff in your code. If you use you have to provide the old solution when they check your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` makes its keys immutable, so references to mutable versions of its keys is not possible without violating `const`-correctness. If you are certain that this version of a map where you're doing lookups by value is correct, then you'll need to roll your own data structure to make this code work.

Alternatively, because I have difficulty believing that that's actually a correct version of your program, consider the following: in all instances where you look-up values in `edges`, you're searching for a `std::string` associated with two `Tnode` objects. It seems pretty clear that the correct data structure for this code is not `std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>`, but `std::map<std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>, Tedge>`. `Tnode` in this case represents half of the key looking up a `Tedge` object, which is how you use it.

Also, you can't return `nullptr` for references. You need to either throw an exception or provide some kind of handling to represent the scenario where you're unable to return the object.

```
void add(Tnode n, Tnode n2, Tedge e) {
    edges.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(n, n2), e));
}

bool has(Tedge edge) const{
    bool l = false;
    for(typename std::map<Tedge, std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end() && !l; it++) {
        l = it -> second == edge;
    }

    return l;
}

const Tedge operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec) const {
    std::map<std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>, Tedge>::const_iterator it = edges.find(std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>(first, sec));
    if(it != edges.end()) 
        return it-> second;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("No such element found");
}

Tedge & operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec) {
    std::map<std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>, Tedge>::iterator it = edges.find(std::pair<Tnode, Tnode>(first, sec));
    if(it != edges.end()) 
        return it-> second;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("No such element found");
}
```

I don't know why you have the restriction of staying within the C++98 subset (if this is a restriction imposed by your professor, then your professor is not so good at their job, I think), but if that restriction can be lifted, then you can dramatically simplify this code:

```
void add(Tnode n, Tnode n2, Tedge e) {
    edges.emplace(std::make_pair(n, n2), e);
}

bool has(Tedge const& edge) const{
    for(auto const& entry : edges) 
        if(entry.second == edge) 
            return true;
    return false;
}

const Tedge operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec) const {
    if(auto it = edges.find(std::make_pair(first, sec)); it != edges.end())
        return it->second;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("No such element found");
}

Tedge & operator()(const Tnode &first, const Tnode &sec) {
    if(auto it = edges.find(std::make_pair(first, sec)); it != edges.end())
        return it->second;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("No such element found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Modifying the key was a stupid idea from me, i don't even know why I wanted to do it. I did it this way, because I have the solution for the other data structure (pair(tnode, tnode), tedge) in the map, but my proff said that he made it a while ago and it should have been made this was as I did. Thats why I was doing it this way, to practice. Yeah the restriction for the 98 reference is from the main professors'. They said something about these are the basics and you should know them or something like that.

Comment: Also we have to write the code in our booklets, and the teacher is doing the same at the whiteboard too. It's pretty ridicolous, because i just write down some C++ code in the lecture but i don't see what it does. He tells us whats the outcome, but come on, it's 2018. Other programming classes were on computers, this is the only exception. Others are more understandable too.